# How to properly route after form submit in React with Redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Originally I wanted to refresh/re-fetch items in list component after submitting and close item's editor form component.

Side note: Before introduce redux to project I did route in `handleSubmit` function right after `axios.put(...)` and obviously didn't have list refreshed because routing happens before asynchronous call completed.

Following snippets shows how I use arrow function as call back to do routing within promise:

in partDetail.js module

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  let part =  this.props.part;
  this.props.updatePart(part, ()=>this.props.history.push('/home'));
    return false;
}
```

in partsActions.js module

```
export function updatePart(part, routeCallback){
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_PART});
        axios.put(`${apiUrl}${part.id}`,part)
            .then(response => {
                routeCallback();
                //dispatch({type: UPDATE_PART_FULFILLED, payload: response.data})
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("updatePart failed submit error: '"+error+"'");
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_PART_REJECTED, payload: error})
            })
    }
}
```

But I have strong feeling that's not proper way to route to view on succeed of asynchronous call in React+Redux. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if a promise is returned on the action `updatePart`, then you can use `then` on `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let { part, updatePart } = this.props; // <-- ES6 destructuring

  updatePart(part).then(() => this.props.history.push('/home'));
  return false;
}
```

On updatePart, adding async will return a Promise:

```
export async function updatePart(part)
```

Comment: I like the idea but not clear how to return promise from update part. I have to `dispatch({type: UPDATE_PART_FULFILLED, payload: response.data})` from there. It wass commented while I'm experimenting.

Comment: @AlexeiP returning Promise.resolve() after the dispatches does the trick, I edited my answer above to reflect that. I believe returning whatever the dispatch or axios throws also works, but I'm not entirely sure of the syntax.

Comment: Should there be any declaration to avoid run-time `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`  @ `updatePart(part).then(() => this.props.history.push('/home'));`

Comment: Sorry yes, no need to return the promise. Simply add: `async` as in `export async function updatePart(part)` and that should work.

Comment: very close!!! Now it throw run-time Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: I add promise to middleware stack `const middleware = [ thunk, promise(), logger];`... :((( Not helping

Comment: `import promise from 'redux-promise'` instead of `import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";` fix the problem it's working!!! But now routing happens before fetch...  Please see side note in original post

Comment: I've got it working by call fetch `updatePart(part).then(() => {this.props.history.push('/home'); this.props.fetchParts();});.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Happy to help! :)